# Route localhost:XXXX to another IP locally

Tags: server, nginx

I have a server in Raspberry Pi, hosted in a docker container. Currently I am accessing via `localhost:8005`or using my IP `192.168.0.101:8005`.

I would like to mask the port number and access it without mentioning the port number. For example `192.168.0.103` or `myserver.example.com`

It is not necessary for me to access it from an external network. I just want to access within my own network to subscribe to MQTT.

I have read about reverse proxies and tried to implement them, but my port`80` is blocked by ISP and I could not get my SSL signed. Is there any other way I can do?

**Updates from comments:**
I know MQTT uses port 1883. The server is actually has a platform that runs on port 8005. The platform can send data through MQTT on port 1883. To subscribe to MQTT, I must type `192.168.0.101:8005 -p 1883` which is not possible. So I want to mask 192.168.0.101:8005 with something else.

I can access my platform at 192.168.0.101:8005 But I have to type this in terminal`mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.0.101:8005 -p 1883 \ -u FAMILY -P XX -t 'FAMILY/location/#'` to subscribe via MQTT to obtain data.

The platform documentation suggests to use Caddy and reverse proxy the server to Web. My ISP has blocked port 80 and I can't get my SSL signed, so that option is not possible. So, I am looking for other alternatives where I can reverse proxy 192.168.0.101:8005 to local IP and use MQTT locally.

Comment: It seems each paragraph in your question is asking about an unrelated thing ... MQTT uses a default port 1883 - most clients that want to connect to MQTT will default to using port 1883 - don't see the problem

Comment: Yes, I know MQTT uses port 1883. The server is actually has a platform that runs on port 8005. The platform can send data through MQTT on port 1883. To subscribe to MQTT, I must type `192.168.0.101:8005 -p 1883` which is not possible. So I want to mask `192.168.0.101:8005` with something else.

Comment: `I must type 192.168.0.101:8005` - where do you type such a thing? in a browser? why is 1883 not possible?

Comment: I can access my platform at `192.168.0.101:8005` But I have to type this in terminal `mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.0.101:8005 -p 1883 \
    -u FAMILY -P XX -t 'FAMILY/location/#'` to subscribe via MQTT to obtain data.

Comment: Lol. Really. You specify a port in the host and as a port number. I think you may be doing it wrong

Comment: The platform documentation suggests to use Caddy and reverse proxy the server to Web. My ISP has blocked port 80 and I can't get my SSL signed, so that option is not possible. So, I am looking for other alternatives where I can reverse proxy `192.168.0.101:8005` to local IP and use MQTT locally.

Comment: `-h 192.168.0.101:8005 -p 1883` makes **no sense** ... `192.168.0.101` is a local IP, so why do you need some poxy for it?